# How to read multiple files in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv, django-rest-framework

I have created command in django that reads a csv file and seeds data to the database. Currently, I can only read one file , how can I read multiple files in a directory with the following implementation below. I think I should have some sort of a list of directories and then for each file I will do the seeding.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import csv
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from elite_schedule.models import Match
SILENT, NORMAL, VERBOSE, VERY_VERBOSE = 0, 1, 2, 3

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from glob import iglob

path=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/data/')
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list_ = []



class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ("Imports movies from a local CSV file. " "Expects title, URL, and release year.")

    # def add_arguments(self, parser):
    #     # Positional arguments
    #     parser.add_argument("file_path",nargs=1,type=str,)


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        verbosity = options.get("verbosity", NORMAL)
        file_path = x
        print(file_path)
        if verbosity >= NORMAL:
            self.stdout.write("=== Matches imported ===")

        for file_ in allFiles:
            with open(file_path) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                # Dont upload header froom csv 
                next(reader)
                for game in reader:
                    division = game[0]
                    date=game[1]
                    home_team = game[2]
                    away_team = game[3]

                    home_goal = game[4]
                    away_goal = game[5]
                    print(home_goal)
                    home_odd = game[23]
                    draw_odd = game[24]
                    away_odd = game[25]
                        # let's skip the column captions
                    # continue
                    """Assign country based on division.
                    to get divisions code details check football.uk
                    """ 
                    try: 
                        if division == "E1" or "E2" or "E3":
                            country = "ENGLAND"
                        elif division == "S1":
                            country = "SPAIN"
                        elif division == "G1":
                            country="GERMANY"
                        elif division == "I1":
                            country = "ITALY"


                            match, created = \
                            Match.objects.get_or_create(
                            division=division,
                            date=date,
                            home_team=home_team,
                            away_team=away_team,
                            home_goal =home_goal,
                            away_goal=away_goal,
                            home_odd=home_odd,
                            draw_odd=draw_odd,
                            away_odd=away_odd,
                            country=country
                            )
                            if verbosity >= NORMAL:
                                self.stdout.write("{}. {}".format(game, match.division))
                    except Exception as e:
                        raise e
```

My data folder is at the root level of django project and the csv folders are organized as follows:

```
├── ENGLAND
│   ├── championship.csv
│   ├── conference.csv
│   ├── league_1.csv
│   ├── league_2.csv
│   ├── notes.txt
│   └── premier_league.csv
├── GERMANY
│   ├── bundesliga_1.csv
│   └── bundesliga_2.csv
├── ITALY
│   ├── seria_a.csv
│   └── seria_b.csv
└── SPAIN
    ├── la_liga_primiera_division.csv
    └──  La_Liga_Segunda Division.csv
```

Comment: Put the code that reads one file into a separate method and use os.walk() to walk the directory (change the argument x to be BASE_DIR).  python standard documentation should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I added all the files in an array and iterated through the array:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import csv
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from elite_schedule.models import Match
SILENT, NORMAL, VERBOSE, VERY_VERBOSE = 0, 1, 2, 3

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

csv_files = ['bundesliga_1.csv','bundesliga_2.csv','eng_championship.csv','eng_conference.csv','eng_league_1.csv','eng_league_2.csv','eng_premier_league.csv','la_liga_primiera_division.csv',' La_Liga_Segunda Division.csv','seria_a.csv','seria_b.csv']

CSV_FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "data")

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ("Imports movies from a local CSV file. " "Expects title, URL, and release year.")

    # def add_arguments(self, parser):
    #     # Positional arguments
    #     parser.add_argument("file_path",nargs=1,type=str,)


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        verbosity = options.get("verbosity", NORMAL)
        for csv_file in csv_files:

            file_path = CSV_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(CSV_FOLDER_PATH,str(csv_file))
            print(file_path)
            if verbosity >= NORMAL:
                self.stdout.write("=== Matches imported ===")
            with open(file_path) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                # Dont upload header froom csv 
                next(reader)
                for game in reader:
                    division = game[0]
                    date=game[1]
                    home_team = game[2]
                    away_team = game[3]

                    home_goal = game[4]
                    away_goal = game[5]
                    print(home_goal)
                    home_odd = game[23]
                    draw_odd = game[24]
                    away_odd = game[25]
                    print(game)
                        # let's skip the column captions
                    # continue
                    """Assign country based on division.
                    to get divisions code details check football.uk
                    """ 
                    try: 

                        match, created = \
                        Match.objects.get_or_create(
                        division=division,
                        date=date,
                        home_team=home_team,
                        away_team=away_team,
                        home_goal =home_goal,
                        away_goal=away_goal,
                        home_odd=home_odd,
                        draw_odd=draw_odd,
                        away_odd=away_odd
                        )
                        if verbosity >= NORMAL:
                            self.stdout.write("{}. {}".format(game, match.division))
                    except Exception as e:
                        raise e
```